v-bind to css in vue3
<style lang="scss">
.starDropGrid {
  --star-border: 2px;
  --star-diameter: v-bind("generateStarStyle.starDiameter");
}

.starDropGrid {
  height: var(--card-height);
  width: var(--card-width);
  border-radius: var(--card-border-radius);

  position: absolute;
  display: flex;

  pointer-events: none;
}

.stars {
  height: var(--star-diameter);
  width: var(--star-diameter);
  border-radius: var(--star-border);

  background-color: white;

  position: absolute;

  animation-name: dropStars;
  animation-duration: random(5) + s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes dropStars {
  0% {
    top: v-bind("generateStarStyle.initTop");
    left: v-bind("generateStarStyle.initLeft");

    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    top: v-bind("generateStarStyle.lastTop");
    left: v-bind("generateStarStyle.lastLeft");

    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>

binding value is working, but there code is error by "All destructured elements are unused.(ts)"
in VSCode.
error range is
'er");'  << in --star-diameter
to
'left: v-bind("gene' << in keyframes 100% left
i can't try another codes because vue3 grammer.
how can i solve that problems?

So, you have a TS error on CSS?

Here is the syntax for v-bind in CSS: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

it solved. maybe this error v-bind to style ref variable.
